# Monetized video streaming services?

Tags: webapp-rec

Are there any existing video streaming services that would provide me the ability to sell individual videos (pay-per-vid/view) or perhaps sell video subscriptions?

Not looking to provide the next Netflix, but to offer streaming (or downloadable) videos for purchase - a similar model to http://www.cleancoders.com/

Comment: If you are looking to provide these on your own web site, take a look at www.dacast.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following services:

- [Movielocker](http://movielocker.com/)
- [MindBites](http://www.mindbites.com/sell)